# Phabricator - review diffs using Spaces for security?

Tags: phabricator

I have a Phabricator install, which is connected to my Git repository. I am trying to implement a Security queue, so that tasks can be restricted to a limited number of core developers to avoid disclosing vulnerabilities. So far, that works great.

However, I think that any patches attached to Security bugs should also be hidden, at least until they are committed. Differential objects don't seem to be able to be part of a Space, and while they can have visibility rules, I can't use Herald to edit those visibility rules.

**How can I restrict the visibility of Differential objects as they are being uploaded?**

I don't necessarily need it to be with Spaces, I can do it with the "Visible To" option and my Security project, but it is not acceptable for users who are not part of the Security space/project to receive Herald notifications, so editing the Diff after it is added is too late.

Comment: Hi Dan, I was wondering if you found a solution to this? I am facing the same issue, I want to be able to restrict visibility while creating the differential itself, any help would be appreciated.